# How do I open the main window and all the other Windows remain hidden untill called?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a bunch of Tk() throughout my program. So when I first run main all these other windows come on to the screen and I have to minimize them to get the main window on front.

How do I prevent these windows from opening and just open the main window?

There are 3 or 4 .py files imported by the main. I've tried `withdraw()`,`iconify()`,`tkraise()` most of the windows are widgets with frames on them as many as 5 on some.import bids

````py
import bids
import jobs
import costs
import accounting
import customers
import labor
import sales
import vendors
import  tkinter as tk 
from job_notes import JobNotes

def Main():
    root1 = tk.Tk()
    a_menu = tk.Menu(root1)
    
    root1.config(menu = a_menu)
    root1.geometry('1600x1275')
    root1.title("The Upper menu box |")

    the_label = tk.Label(root1,text= " *****   Use The Menu Above for Menu Implementation  ******       ",font=('verdana',42,'bold'),relief='raised')
    the_label.grid(row=0,column=0) 
    label1 = tk.Label(root1,text="1.To Create a Bid select (File: 'Create an Estimate' from the menu above",font=('verdana',18,'bold'),relief ="raised")
    label1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10)
    label2 = tk.Label(root1,text="2.To Change a Bid into a Job select View/Edit: 'View/Edit an Estimate' than Confirm the Bid",font=('verdana',18,'bold'))
    label2.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=10)
    label3 = tk.Label(root1,text="3.To view/edit a Job go to View/Edit: 'View/Edit a Job'",font=('verdana',18,'bold'))
    label3.grid(row=3,column=0,pady=10)
    
    file_menu = tk.Menu(a_menu)
    a_menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file_menu)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Create an Estimate", command=bids.bid.create_bid)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Create Sales Order",command=sales.create_salesorder)   
    file_menu.add_command(label="Create a work order",command=jobs.Jobs.create_workorder)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Create an Invoice",command=sales.create_an_invoice)
    file_menu.add_separator()
    file_menu.add_command(label="Enter A Customer",command=customers.Customer.enter_customer)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Enter A Vendor",command=vendors.enter_vendor)
    edit_menu = tk.Menu(a_menu) 
    a_menu.add_cascade(label="View/Edit",menu=edit_menu)
    edit_menu.add_command(label="View/Edit an estimate",command=bids.bid.edit_bid)
    edit_menu.add_command(label="View/Edit Jobs",command=jobs.Jobs.tree_to_view_jobs)
    edit_menu.add_command(label="View/Edit a Work Order",command=jobs.Jobs.edit_work_order)
    edit_menu.add_separator()
    edit_menu.add_command(label="View/Edit Customer info",command=customers.edit_customer)
    edit_menu.add_command(label="View/Edit a Vendor",command=vendors.edit_vendor)

    add_menu = tk.Menu(a_menu) 
    a_menu.add_cascade(label="Add",menu=add_menu)
    add_menu.add_command(label="Add costs",command=costs.Costs.add_cost)
    add_menu.add_command(label="Add Labor",command=labor.Labor.add_labor)
    add_menu.add_command(label="add_change_order",command=jobs.change_order)
    add_menu.add_separator()
    add_menu.add_command(label="Add Notes to job",command=jobs.add_notes)
    add_menu.add_separator()
    add_menu.add_command(label="Add a vendor invoice",command=vendors.add_vendor_invoice)   
    add_menu.add_command(label="Add Notes to Bid",command=bids.bid.add_notes)

    view_menu = tk.Menu(a_menu)
    a_menu.add_cascade(label="View",menu=view_menu)
    view_menu.add_command(label="View Jobs",command=jobs.view_jobs)
    view_menu.add_command(label="View Work Orders",command=jobs.view_work_orders)
    view_menu.add_separator()
    view_menu.add_command(label="View Customers",command=customers.view_customers)
    view_menu.add_command(label="View Vendors",command=vendors.view_vendors)

    admin_menu = tk.Menu(a_menu)
    a_menu.add_cascade(label="Administrations",menu=admin_menu)
#       # approve vendor invoice(costs), confirm sales invoices(sales), finished jobs, accounts receivables
#       # accounts payable, general ledger, general journal,balance sheet,income statement
#       #employee payroll,Sales reports with a drop down menu, by customer, by date, by amounts
#       #pay sales comission, vendor rates drop down menu desc,rate

#       # add - to schedule

    
    root1.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    Main() ```

this is main.py as you can see there are a number of import an in those imports ther are multiple Tk() functions
the answer is root1.focus_force() right above root1.mainloop()
````

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried. That said, from the wording of your question it sounds like your app contains *multiple instances of Tk* - this is likely the problem. You probably want your main window to be an instance of `Tk`, and the others should be instances of `Toplevel`. Post  your code and we can help out.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The answer to "how to prevent windows from appearing" could be as simple as "don't make the window until you're ready for it to appear".  Also, the methods you mentioned are the right methods. It's not clear why you think they aren't working.

Comment: @BryanOakley under windows they behave a little different on start, but at least `withdraw` should have an effect.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: what do you mean? How does it behave differently on windows?

Comment: @BryanOakley If you have two windows open the root window is on the front, despite the other window is focused. I have read somewhere in the source that, that is for a windows specific *brain..*. The canonical way of handling it is to use `-topmost, true` and then back to `false`. A similar issue is also noted in the python tkinter `test.py` where they use a different approach to solve it, but I belief that is solved by tkinter internally nowadays or at least disappeared way back when I was working freshly with windows 10.

Comment: im on a mac, and these windows are spread out over like 3 or 4 py files with main being the one with a menu bar at top

Answer (score 0):

i figured out how to get the main window to come up in front of the other tkinter windows that are created by my imports

root1.focus_force()
called it right before
root1.mainloop()